# How to implement Rest APIs in monolithic architecture

Tags: rest, soap, microservices, soa

I understand (somewhat) what are differences between monolithic , microservices .
And also what is SOA it is a service consumer/provider architecture and microservice is subset of SOA. and they use Restfull/SOAP APIs to communicate.
So when a a request something he/she does using Rest/SOAP API but how in a Monolithic architecture a client request through which API? I searched all the links/blogs on google, videos on youtube but still I am not clear about this.

Or may be my whole understanding is not correct.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you are a bit confused, I would really recommend you picking up a book on the subject.

Monolithic vs micoservice application is more about how you package and deploy your application and in some sense how coupled modules/subsystems are. The extreme example: you always deploy the entire monolithic applications for the smallest possible change, and in the microservice example you just need to make the same change to one service.

Rest API and SOAP are protocols for how (http) messages are passed between client <-> server and has nothing to do with monolithic vs micro.

Monolithic application can of course have public http API's, and it might not be possible for a user (sending request) of that API to tell the architecture style of that application. And why would she care about that?

I think this is a nice start: https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html